# Select points that are inside a polygon layer using aggregate function in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression

I have two layers (polygons and points) in a geopackage (area_and_points.gpkg, [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P2J_ijktzTvgpk9rLsR_tTKmMAWBO2El/view)). I need to extract all point that lie within the polygons and also inherit one attribute (`Name` in this case) from that polygons. I want to use aggregate expression to solve this. I used the following "Geometry Generator" code on the points layer. I get an empty layer.

```
aggregate(
layer:='polygons', 
   aggregate:='collect', 
   expression:=intersection(geometry(@parent),$geometry),
   filter:=intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry) 
)
```

[image]

It even shows "Preview: <geometry: MultiPoint>". But the result is that there is no actual filtering and the generator geometry (**Modified geometry**) has all the points (15 in this case) as shown in the image below. I would be happy to get any solution using `expression`.

[image]

I am not even getting the points filtered what to speak of adding the attribute (`Name`).

Comment: In the geopackage you provided, the polygon layer is empty (containing 0 features).

Comment: Sorry about that. The polygons are restored.

Comment: Should actually work. Check if both layers are in the same CRS.

Comment: The expression works, but it will not add any new attributes (name of polygon the points are located within). Creating a new attribute **and** a selection of the points is not possible in one step/expression using QGIS expressions alone. Also be aware to use the full layer name instead of just `polygons` in line 2. In the sample project you provided, this worked: `aggregate(
layer:='polygons_e2b7c2ad_6eec_4a0a_b6cc_2b580b12acef', 
   aggregate:='collect', 
   expression:=intersection(geometry(@parent),$geometry),
   filter:=intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry) 
)`

Comment: Geometry generator is not for creating new attributes ("inherit one attribute (`Name` in this case) from that polygons") and neither does it "extract all point that lie within the polygons". It simply creates a new style for all those points that fulfill the condition. If you want to work with the "extracted" points, you must either create a new attribute and run processing based on that or create a new layer with only the features you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different options: 1) select points inside polygons and copy/paste them to a new layer (fastest and easiest); 2) Virtual layer (most elegant) 3) using QGIS expressions (a bit cumbersome with with some shortcomings). In detail:

*Remark: changing you layer names to something easier than `area_and_points(1) — points` could be a good idea.*

### Solution 1: copy/paste selected features

Use [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#selecting-features) to select the points inside the polygons using `overlay_within ('polygons')` (use the name of your polygon layer).

Then copy/paste the selected features to a new layer. Add the name of the polygon layer they are within using the expression in step 1 of solution 3 below.

### Solution 2: virtual layer

Create a virtual layer with this query:

```
select *, pt.geometry 
from "area_and_points(1) — points" as pt, 
"area_and_points(1) — polygons" as poly
where st_within ( pt.geometry, poly.geometry)
```

[image]

### Using QGIS expressions

1. Create a new attribute `name` on the point layer with this expression, using Field calculator:

   ```
   overlay_within(
       'polygons_e2b7c2ad_6eec_4a0a_b6cc_2b580b12acef',
       name
   )[0]
   ```
2. Extract the points that are within polygons to a new layer with [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) and the following expression:

   ```
   case 
   when 
       overlay_within(
           'polygons_e2b7c2ad_6eec_4a0a_b6cc_2b580b12acef'
       )
   then $geometry
   end
   ```

   However, you will get a layer with all features from the initial layer, but the points outside polygons will come without features (only attributes) - so you probably want to delete these using [Remove null geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#remove-null-geometries)

Comment: Thanks. I learned many things